# Generating load time serial number for PCB application

Tags: c

I am trying to generate an incrementing value at load time to be used to "serialize" a PCB with a unique code value.  Not an expert in ld or preprocessor commands, so looking for some help.

The value will be used in a unique ID for each board that the code is loaded on and will also be used as a counter for boards in the field.

I have no preconceived idea of how I might accomplish this, so any workable answer to get me started, including a pre-preprocessor macro is fine.  In my olden days, I recollect adding a couple lines to the linker file that would accomplish this, but I have been unable to resurrect that information anywhere (including my brain's memory cells).

The simpler the answer, the better.

Comment: "trying to generate an incrementing value at load time to be used to "serialize" a PCB with a unique code value." --> post the code that shows your try.

Comment: Please explain more about your goal. Spend some descrition of how the results should be. How should your code behave? You seem to want to write a macro. Probably to simplify something which you currently do manually. Show that manual way of achieving what you want to make more convenient.

Comment: @Yunnosch: If you've done embedded release control this question is abundantly clear. He's trying to do something at compile time that is better done at board flash time.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem was remarkably simple.

The binary contained

```
const char *serial = "XY-00000";
```

I then wrote a short program that boiled down to:

```
char uniqueserial [8];
/* Generate serial - this was an SQL call to the manufacturing DB */
char *array;
/* Read binary into array */
memcpy(memmem(array, "XY-00000",8), uniqueserial,8);
/* Write array to temp bin file for flashing */
```

Depends on the serial template string being unique in the binary. Use strings command to check. I disable crc protected object files due to taste. I like my embedded binaries being exact memory dumps.

Answer (score 0):

The linker is not the right place for two reasons:

- the executable can be loaded with the same id in several devices, making your approach void.
- You should have to link the executable for each device you are programming, which poses an spent of cpu resources.

The best place is to patch the executable at loading time with the serial number.

Select a data patern as token to initialize your variable with the device id (a pattern difficult to happen elsewhere in your program binary) and initialize your serial number variable to that data pattern (better if you do it statically initializing an array variable or something similar)

Make a program to be executed on each download to device that search for the pattern in the executable file, before loading the binary program into the device and writes the correct value to be programmed into the device (beware that you are patching a binary, so you cannot think on variable lenght strings or the like, that can trash all the work made by the linker)

Once patched the binary executable, you can download it to the device.

Another solution is to reserve a fixed area in your linker script for all this kind of information.  Then, put all your device information variables there.  Then get the exact positions in rom for the individual variables and include the proper data in the loaded image.  In this case, the linker is your friend, reserving some fixed segment in your device's rom allocated for storing the device's individual data (you can put there mac addresses, serial numbers, default configuration, etc.)